# Has anyone tried a port from Expression Engine to Craft using Verbb's Feed Me plugin?

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm in the process of scoping out a project in Craft, which requires porting an existing site built in EE. The EE site in question relies quite heavily on relationships (using Playa) and not I'm 100% sure how/if Feed Me will be able to retain those relationships when importing into Craft.

Is this possible? Or will we have to remap the relationships *after* importing the content?

Answer (score 1):

If you import the related items first then you should be able to make the relationship when you import the parent entries.

However, it's really down to the complexity of the relationships.

You may find it simpler to do the import in stages. Start with the bare bones to create entries with the appropriate names/slugs and then bring in the other data bit by bit.

I would favour using XML or JSON for my import format.

I also find it useful to also include some craft fields into which I import the legacy EE id (and any other pertinent information).

Comment: Thanks foamcow. The relationships aren't that complex but pretty much every entry relies on them. It's for an art gallery, where we have a channel for Artists and a channel for Art. When a new piece of art is added, the related artist is chosen via a single entry Playa field. It's this relationship that I'm keen to retain. So based on your comment, you'd suggest importing art first, then artists?

Comment: Yes, import the artists first. But as mentioned, you can import the art first if you want. Then import the artists and then after that re-run the art import to get the artist relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’ll run a few tests I think and see how I get on. Cheers.